# Grab image from screen to numpy array and display it as black and white image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read image data from a certain part of the screen, so I can post-process it in a form of a `numpy` array.  This is what I tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(798, 166, 300, 400))  # (bbox=x,y,width,height)
img_np = np.array(img)
```

But when I try to print `img_np`, it returns:

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=0x234 at 0x109F8F0>
```

It doesn't seem like it's an `numpy` array.  I also want to display the black and white image from the `numpy` array to verify what I am doing is right (and also display processed `numpy` arrays in the future).  Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are type(img) and img_np.dtype?

Comment: The type for `img` is `<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>` and `img_np.dtype` returns `object`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your

```
(bbox=798, 166, 300, 400))
```

the **x=798** is over your screen

so you must make your (x,y) in your screen.

look this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mIT.jpg)
the result is None ,because it cant capture your screen

and when I modify the x=100,it works 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfYub.jpg)

the code:

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import ImageGrab,Image 
img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(798,166,300,400))  #798
# img=Image.open("Modric.jpg")
print(type(img))
img_np=np.array(img)
print(type(img_np))
print(img_np.shape)
```

result:

```
<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
()      *******None
```

after **x=100**:

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import ImageGrab,Image 
img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(100,166,300,400))  #798
# img=Image.open("Modric.jpg")
print(type(img))
img_np=np.array(img)
print(type(img_np))
print(img_np.shape) code here
```

result:

```
<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(234, 200, 3)
```

the right x coord and in screen, it can works

---

I am sorry for the first question,the right is here

```
import tkinter
win=tkinter.Tk()
width=win.winfo_screenwidth()   #get your screen's width
height=win.winfo_screenheight() #get your screen's height  
print(width,height)                            
img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(300,400,width,height)).convert("L")  #798
img_np=np.array(img)
print(img_np.shape)
```

result:

```
1536 864
(464, 1236)
```

when you use the bbox=(x,y,width,height)   ,the pixel counting method is width-x and height-y . so you must make your width>x and height>y and it works

---

as for convert to gray image,you can use opencv

```
import cv2
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_np,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)[enter link description here][3]
```

**link**
    or
the PIL convert("L")  function

```
img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(300,400,width,height)).convert("L")  #798

 or
```

the formula:

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
"""
gray=0.299*R+0.587*G+0.144*B
"""
return np.uint8(np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]))
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Ma Jun pointed out the 
(bbox=x,y,width,height) is not really like start from (x,y) and get a width to height window. 
Rather the opening window is x,y width-x, height-y 
I added this post because it took me a long time to figure this out :) 
keywords: Python ImageGrab bbox