# Python: cannot import name 'rgb2gray' from 'skimage.color'

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-image

When I try:

```
>>> from skimage import io
```

I get at the end the following:

```
from ..color import rgb2gray
ImportError: cannot import name 'rgb2gray' from 'skimage.color' (C:\Users\user\A
ppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\__init_
_.py)
```

Although I have installed the packages: matplotlib, scipy, pillow, numpy and six

How can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you installed "scikit-image" package ?? If yes, then have you tried "from skimage.color import rgb2gray" ??

Comment: Yes, i have installed scikit-image, when i tried from skimage.color import rgb2gray, i get the same error that I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 8):

In case you run into this error from inside a Jupyter Notebook, try restarting the kernel [as suggested in this GitHub issue.](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3273)

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't installed *`scikit-image`* package.

Try this on terminal:

```
pip install -U scikit-image
```

And then try importing like this:

```
from skimage import io
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
```

If you still got the *error or you have installed the package* previously, 
[try reinstalling the package first.](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html)

If it still don't resolve your issue, then try updating the following packages:

`matplotlib`, `scipy`, `pil`, `numpy` and `six`

However, try not to *import all of the subpackages* to *improve loading time*. You can however try something like:

```
from skimage import color
...
gray_img = color.rgb2gray(img)
```

If you still got errors, *make sure that you are using the correct python kernel and dependent modules are updated and installed*.

If that did not help either, then try [*`Anaconda`*](https://www.anaconda.com/download/), it come with many *pre-installed* packages.

Leave a comment if you still have a problem :)

Comment: I have installed scikit-image and I still have the same error when I write from skimage.color import rgb2gray

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what can I do also?

Comment: Please see my updated answer and let me know the output :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I apply what you say but unfortunately still have the same error :(

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling "skimage" (scikit-image) module ??

Comment: "gray_img = color.rgb2gray(img) gives a syntax error: can't assign to operator

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the python 3.7 kernel ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure ... i am using python 3.7.1

Comment: Try using `Anaconda` then.

Comment: I have to download Anaconda?

Comment: Yes, try download + install `Anaconda` , it comes with several python modules.

Comment: If it helped, you can accept the answer, so others may get help in time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179959/discussion-between-mohammad-zain-abbas-and-user10254054).

Answer (score 0):

three ways to convert  RGB2Gray:

opencv:

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("file.jpg",0)   [enter link description here][1]
```

or  you can do this:

```
img=cv2.imread("file.jpg")
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

**cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY** beacause it reads BGR mode.

another methods you can look this link:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305280/grab-image-from-screen-to-numpy-array-and-display-it-as-black-and-white-image)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once when I import `skimage` using `env conda` on Jupyter. I installed by `pip` or `conda` in env, that error happened. However, after restart the Jupyter, it worked.